# Prevent outer component mark up to be rendered

Tags: angular

I am importing a component into my page:

```
<div>
<p>Here is my component:</p>
<my-component></my-component>
</div>
```

How can I prevent the physical HTML of `<my-component></my-component>` from being rendered in the markup, and just use the html there has been declared within the my-component template?

Right now I get:

```
    <div>
    <p>Here is my component:</p>
    <my-component><div>This is the inner html</div></my-component>
    </div>
```

Whereas I want:

```
        <div>
        <p>Here is my component:</p>
        <div>This is the inner html</div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In component definition, you can set `selector: '[my-component]'`, and treat it like directive, i.e.

```
<div my-component>This is the inner html</div>
```

then the component tag won't show up.

Comment: Aw that's perfect! Thanks so much :)